# Xamarin forms Horizontal listview showing images from ObservableCollection

Tags: xaml, listview, xamarin.forms, observablecollection, binding-context

I want to display Images/Thumbnails of photos that I've been taking in a horizontal view as a part of my content page.
I've stored the images paths as strings in a ObservableCollection. What's the best approach to do this in XAML and PCL.
Would be great if 3 or something images are shown on the screen, and standard image if no images have been added or if string is null, and to have these in a scrollview or listview so that all of the images in the ObservableCollection could be displayed.

[maybe something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDFBo.png)

/Oliver

Answer (score 2):

Use Bindable (Horizontal) Scroll View. see this link it's help you.

http://www.fabiocozzolino.eu/a-little-and-simple-bindable-horizontal-scroll-view/